# Firebase verifyPhoneNumber with flutter is is giving me an error. I cannoty verify

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working for an authentication with phone number in flutter. I am encountering an error with this.

Here is my code:

```
    Future sendOTP() async {


      await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          print("VERIFICATION completed");
          
        },
        verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
          print('VERIFICATION ERROR');

        },
        codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
          print('CODE SENT');

            verID = verificationId;
            token = resendToken;

        },
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
          //print("VERIFICATION timeout");
        },
    );
  }
```

After sending the OTP to the phone number, and after the user triggers the send button, this method will fire;

```
  void HandleOTP() async {
    final _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    final AuthCredential authCredential = await PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
      smsCode: smsCode,
      verificationId: verID,
    );



    print(authCredential);

    await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(authCredential);
  }
```

and here is the problem that is printing in the console

> I/flutter ( 5939): AuthCredential(providerId: phone, signInMethod: phone, token: null)
>
> E/flutter ( 5939): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: [firebase_auth/invalid-verification-id] The verification ID used to create the phone auth credential is invalid.
>
> E/flutter ( 5939): #0      MethodChannelFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential (package:firebase_auth_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase_auth.dart:445:7)
>
> E/flutter ( 5939): <asynchronous suspension>
>
> E/flutter ( 5939): #1      FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart:497:7)
>
> E/flutter ( 5939): <asynchronous suspension>
>
> E/flutter ( 5939): #2      _OTPState.authenticate (package:rice_on_the_go/authentication/OTP.dart:215:5)
>
> E/flutter ( 5939): <asynchronous suspension>

As you see, the value of the credential token is NULL, and why is that null? I hope someone help me to answer this.

Second, why is my verification ID is invalid? I checked it and it is not null.

Please help me solving this because I have been working for this for more than a day now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I make a common function for Firebase PhoneAuth you can try this:

```
Future<void> callPhoneAuth({required String phoneNumber, required void 
Function(String, int?) codeSent, int? forceResendingToken}) async {
await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
  verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
   kPrint('phoneauth is an -------- verifynumber ${credential}');
  },
  codeSent: codeSent,
  timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
  codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
  forceResendingToken: forceResendingToken,
  verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
    if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
      kPrint('phoneauth is an ---- The provided phone number is not valid.');
    }
  });
  }
```

Use like this:

```
       callPhoneAuth(
                    phoneNumber: '+1123456789', //Here your phone number with country dial code
                    codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
                    //This function called when your Otp successfully set it to phone number
                    });
```

Comment: Please try this code first if error throw then tell me so i'm help you to solve that problem.